# Windows batch nested function syntax inside function

Tags: windows, batch-file, nested, conditional-statements, mklink

I am having problems with my nested if syntax, i keep getting the error:

```
'ELSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

here is the function:

```
:makejunction
set LOCALFOLDER=%~1
set QIFOLDER=%~2
pushd %LOCALFOLDER% 2>nul
IF errorlevel 1 (
    IF EXIST %LOCALFOLDER% ( 
        del "%LOCALFOLDER%" 
    )
)
ELSE  
(
    rmdir /S /Q "%LOCALFOLDER%"
)
mklink /J "%LOCALFOLDER%" "%QIFOLDER%"
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Retagged bash to batch

Answer (score 1):

`else` and the parentheses must be on the same line:

```
:makejunction
set "LOCALFOLDER=%~1"
set "QIFOLDER=%~2"
pushd "%LOCALFOLDER%" 2>nul
IF errorlevel 1 (
    IF EXIST "%LOCALFOLDER%" del "%LOCALFOLDER%" 
) ELSE (
    rmdir /S /Q "%LOCALFOLDER%"
)
mklink /J "%LOCALFOLDER%" "%QIFOLDER%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the else to be directly after the if, hence the `(`:

```
:makejunction
set LOCALFOLDER=%~1
set QIFOLDER=%~2
pushd %LOCALFOLDER% 2>nul
IF errorlevel 1 (
    IF EXIST %LOCALFOLDER% ( 
        del "%LOCALFOLDER%" 
    )
) ELSE (
    rmdir /S /Q "%LOCALFOLDER%"
)
mklink /J "%LOCALFOLDER%" "%QIFOLDER%"
```

And that should work fine

Mona